# Print else only once?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, parsing, for-loop

how do I get my else print to only print once instead of for every row that the string doesn't exist? I tried moving it around by tabbing back a couple of layers but it doesn't work. I understand the logic, I but don't know how to limit it. I'm adding a little bit at a time to my parsing scripts for practice, learning as I go, but this one got me. Thanks!

```
import csv
# Testing finding something specifical in a CSV, with and else
testpath = 'C:\Users\Devin\Downloads\users.csv'
developer = "devin"

with open (testpath, 'r') as testf:
    testr = csv.reader(testf)
    for row in testr:
        for field in row:
            if developer in row:
                print row
        else:
            print developer +  " does not exist!"
```

Comment: Should that be `if developer in field:` in your code? (not `in row:`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python, you can have an `else` clause attached to your `for` loop. For example

```
>>> for i in range(10):
...     if i == 5: break # this causes the else statement to be skipped
... else:
...     print 'not found'
...
```

Note `5` was found so the else statement is not executed

```
>>> for i in range(10):
...     if i == 15: break
... else:
...     print 'not found'
...
not found
```

See the [documentation on for statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for)

> A break statement executed in the first suite terminates the loop
>   without executing the else clause’s suite. A continue statement
>   executed in the first suite skips the rest of the suite and continues
>   with the next item, or with the else clause if there is no next item.

Comment: What a valuable information. Never knew this!

Comment: Raymond Hettinger suggested `nobreak` keyword to be introduced, however the proposal never got through... more [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSGv2VnC0go#t=17m12s)

Comment: @mentalita thanks for the link. I agree that it's a bit confusing in it's current implementation

Comment: Thanks @PeterGibson! Break is what I was looking for, make sense. I wonder why my question was voted down, the thread they claimed answered my question doesn't answer my question...

Answer (score 3):

See Gibson's answer first. You can do this:

```
for row in testr:
    found = False
    for field in row:
        if developer in row:
            print row
            found = True
            break
    if found: break
else:
    print developer +  " does not exist!"
```

You can also omit the `found` flag (as suggested by *Jean-François Fabre* in the comment) but this makes a bit hard to understand imo (I had to compile in my head):

```
for row in testr:       
    for field in row:
        if developer in row:
            print row
            # We found the developer. break from the inner loop.
            break
    else:
        # This means, the inner loop ran fully, developer was not found.
        # But, we have other rows; we need to find more.
        continue
    # This means, the else part of the inner loop did not execute.
    # And that indicates, developer was found. break from the outer loop.
    break
else:
    # The outer loop ran fully and was not broken
    # This means, developer was not found.
    print developer, "does not exist!"
```

Comment: the `found` flag isn't useful. You could use the `else` trick in the inner loop too.

Comment: True. Answer updated. Thanks.